# Memoization of recursive functions in Python, but only for the duration of the top-level call

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, python-decorators, memoization

I am writing a top-down parser which consists of a top-level function that initiates a recursive parse down the text with lower-level functions. Note that the lower-level functions never call the top-level function, but the lower-level functions are mutually recursive.

I noticed that the parser runs somewhat slowly, and I suspect this to be caused by exponential growth in the recursion, because the parser might repeatedly try to parse the same type of object on the same text at the same offset, resulting in wasted effort.

For this reason I want to memoize the lower-level function calls, but after the top-level function returns, I want to clear the memoization cache to release the memory.

That means that if the user calls the top-level function multiple times with the same parameters, the program should actually go through the whole parsing procedure again.

My motivation is that it is unlikely the same text will be parsed at top-level multiple times, so the memory overhead is not worth it (each parse will generate a fairly large cache).

One possible solution is to rewrite all the lower-level functions to take an additional cache argument like this:

```
def low_level_parse(text, start, cache):
    if (text, start) not in cache:
        # Do something to compute a result
        # ...
        cache[(text, start)] = result

    return cache[(text, start)]
```

and rewrite all calls to the low-level functions to pass down the cache argument (which is initially set to `{}` in the top-level function).

Unfortunately there are many low-level parse functions, and each may also call other low-level parse functions many times. Refactoring the code to implement caching this way would be very tedious and error prone.

Another solution would be to use decorators, and I believe this would be best in terms of maintainability, but I don't know how to implement the memoize decorator in such a way that its cache exists only during the top-level function scope.

I also thought of defining the cache as a global variable in my module, and clear it explicitly after returning from the top-level function. This would spare me the need to modify the low-level functions to take the cache argument explicitly, and I could then use a memoize decorator that makes use of the global cache. But I am not sure the global cache would be a good idea if this is used in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: One option is make a class -- the memoization cache is a member. Different threads can implement their own instance. If there is any chance of moving to multithreaded environment, you can't use globals for the cache (without defeating the purpose with locks). Although I don't know why you say refactoring to use a memoization parameter is harder than refractoring to use memization.

Comment: The reason for the refactoring issue is that in order to use the cache parameter explicitly, I need to modify the control flow of each parse function, and modify each call to pass the cache argument. With the decorator I only need to add a single @memoize line on top of each function definition (and then I can also modify the memoization code at only a single place instead of having to fix all other functions).

Comment: Oh, almost forgot to say -- don't suspect. This is easy to test, so test it. http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Well, I experimentally know that the parser is slow. My hypothesis was that it is due to lack of memoization, so I need to implement that to check if it speeds things up. That's also another reason for my reluctance to tedious refactoring: I don't actually know if this will solve the speed problem.

Comment: A trick to make refactorization easier: pass cache as an optional parameter with default None. You don't actually have to pass it for the function to still work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to [Decorators with Arguments](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845) which I think is what is needed here:

```
class LowLevelProxy:

    def __init__(self, cache):
        self.cache = cache

    def __call__(self, f):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            key = (f,args)    # <== had to remove kwargs as dicts cannot be keys
            if key not in self.cache:
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                self.cache[key] = result

            return self.cache[key]
        return wrapped_f
```

**NB** each function that is wrapped will have its own section in the cache.

you might be able to wrap each of your low level functions like this:

```
@LowLevelProxy(cache)
def low_level(param_1, param_2):
    # do stuff
```